# Issue with Div content spanning to the footer of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, html

Quick question here. Ive been trying to get my content section of my code to fill the page down to the footer. Ive tried to add the following hack to the css for the content type padding-bottom: 5000px margin-bottom: -5000px;  Ive also followed this guide but I didnt not get the result I was looking for. 
Here is a screen shot of what is happening:
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v189/shadowtyper/screenshotIssue_zpse858c39a.gif

```
<div data-role="page" id="Ids" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Accepted Orders
    </h1>
    <a href="#page" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" id="intro" class="ui-btn-right"></a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="idsContent" data-theme="a">
            <li><a href="#somediv"> ID #12345678</a></li>
            <li><a href="#somediv"> ID #12345678</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="footer-docs" data-theme="b">
    <p>footer</p>    
</div>
```

Comment: By "down to the footer" do you mean that you want the lower blue bar to sit on the lower edge of the viewport? What guide? We'd need some CSS or an example page to be of much help.

Comment: Try first to set height of your content to be 100%; if you dont have result on your emulator you can set some background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an working solution, I am using it in my

```
$("div[data-role='page']").live('pageshow',function(e,data){    
    var header = $("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
        content.height(content_height);
    } 
});
```

And here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BYufW/

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.